# How to check if something is still in a collisionshape2d the frame after a collision is detected?

Tags: collision-detection, godot, godot4

I am making a pong clone. This is my code for when something touches the ball:

```
func _on_body_entered(body):
    rotation = -rotation
    speed = -speed
    if speed.x >= 0:
        speed.x = randf_range(0, large)
    else:
        speed.x = randf_range(-large, 0)
    if speed.y >= 0:
        speed.y = randf_range(0, large)
    else:
        speed.y = randf_range(-large, 0)
    var distance = position.distance_to(body.position)
    var x = true
    while x == true:
        if distance > 0:
            if distance > 90:
                distance -= 90
            else:
                x = false
        elif distance <= 0:
            if distance < -90:
                distance += 90
            else:
                x = false
    rotation_degrees += distance
    skew = randf_range(-90, 90)
    await get_tree().create_timer(0.15).timeout
    skew = 0
    Globalvariables.score += 1
```

How do I check if the ball is still touching the paddle in the next frame, so I can turn it 180 degrees (to avoid it going inside the paddle)?

I tried using a variable to check if something was also touching it last frame, but that didn't work, as the `on_body_entered` function only triggers when something starts to touch it. I also tried doing the same thing, but also utilising the `on_body_exited` function.

Answer (score 0):

Using body entered and body existed should work, and usually a good a approach.

I also want to mention that if you are trying to await a frame, you can actually await a graphics frame:

```
await get_tree().process_frame
```

Or a physics frame:

```
await get_tree().physics_frame
```

---

Assuming you are using an `Area2D` (and not a `RigidBody2D` which are also capable of detecting collisions). You might also use `overlaps_body`:

```
if overlaps_body(body):
    # something
```

Or similarly, but more expensive, you could read what `get_overlapping_bodies()` returns and check if if the body you want is in there:

```
if get_overlapping_bodies().has(body):
    # something
```

Try it. See if it works for you.

---

The above approach might not be good enough because Godot caches the values from the last physics step (so if you call them during the physics step, you are getting the values from the prior physics step).

Furthermore, you didn't say `Area2D`, you said `CollisionShape2D` and an `Area2D` or a `PhysicsBody2D` (such as `RigidBody2D`) could have multiple `CollisionShape2D`...

If you want an up to date check, and you want to check only a `CollisionShape2D`, we need to use a lower level API:

```
var query := PhysicsShapeQueryParameters2D.new()
query.shape = $CollisionShape2D.shape
query.transform = $CollisionShape2D.global_transform
var result := get_world_2d().direct_space_state.intersect_shape()

var overlapping := false
for entry in result:
    if entry["collider"] == body:
        overlapping = true
        break

if overlapping:
    # something
```

Comment: That makes sense, but I don't really understand how to implement it.

Comment: @PRDas Are you still struggling with this? I do not know what I can improve about the answer to help.